# Encountering a user suggest too many minor changes

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I've encounter many times, a user that his only edit changes are **Capitalize letter i => I**.
This is too minor and as a result I gave him **Reject[Too minor]**.

The user is keep popping up with the same "changes" and isn't learning nothing.

**Problem:**

1. The user keep appearing with *Suggests edits* every few posts with the same "fixes" - Annoying.
2. Must of the users are marking it as *Too Minor* but there were times that i tried to *Reject* but I got as a response *The edit was already Approved* - That is too bad because that he probably got away and not for the first time.

Is there something I can do, in order to let the user stop with this minor changes that causing those 2 problems?

Comment: Keep rejecting; if enough suggestions are rejected the user receives an automatic ban.

Comment: I failed to understand why OP tagged this as feature-request.

Comment: Why is this change "too minor"? Were there other changes they could have made in the posts you saw?

Comment: @AndrewT., I've tried submitting it, and it gave me an error that I must add a `bug` or `feature-request` tag. Did I post it at the wrong place ?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, I've so that the users only changing capitalize letter i to I, the despite the post needed a lot more. And it was a repeating pattern.

Comment: @OrelEraki You posted this on correct site. However, it should be more probable to tag this as `discussion` out of 4 tags (`bug`, `feature-request`, `discussion`, and `support`). Regarding your question, yes, keep rejecting, or suggest a better edit if possible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and Andrew, Thank you.

Comment: I saw that behaviour too. I keep on rejecting though I approved a few instances where lowercase I was the only problem.